# Measurability of derivative

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I am having difficulties with the following problem:
Let $I$ be an open interval of $\mathbb{R}$ and $f:I\to \mathbb{R}$ measurable Lebesgue on $I$. Suppose that $f$ si derivable on $I$. I have to show that $f'$ is also measurable Lebesgue. 
I thought to try with the definition, but how can I show that $f'^{-1(}(-\infty,a))$ is measurable, for each $a \in\ \mathbb{R}$?Any suggestion, please?

Answer (score 3):

For $x \in I$, let $$f_n(x) =
\begin{cases}
  n(f(x+1/n)-f(x)) & \text{if } x+1/n \in I \\
  0 & \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}$$
To conclude that $f'$ is measurable is enough to notice that $f_n$ is measurable and converges to $f'$.

Comment: Clearly, $f_{n}$ converges to $f'$, bt why are the functions $f_{n}$ measurables?

Comment: @user308560 Algebra of measurable functions...

Comment: Addition: You don't need to assume that $f $ is measurable to begin with. Since it is differentiable,  it is continuous and hence measurable.

Comment: That's correct, PhoemueX