# measurability of a function $f'$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, measurable-functions

> If $f : I\to \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable almost everywhere, where $I$ is an open interval, show that $f'$ is Lebesgue measurable.

I know that pointwise limits of measurable functions are measurable and that if $f$ is differentiable everywhere, $f'$ is measurable (for instance, I can use a technique similar to [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1636136/measurability-of-derivative)). I also know that $f'$ must agree with its restriction to $I\backslash E$ almost everywhere, where $E$ is the set of points on which $f$ isn't differentiable.

My issue is that $f'$ may not even be defined sometimes, so why can't we just restrict $f'$ to $I\backslash E$ and conclude it's measurable because it's only defined on $I\backslash E$?

Comment: A function that equals almost everywhere to a measurable function is itself measurable.